# How to make three intersecting venn diagrams in R with following dataframe available

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I have four dataframes df1,df2,df3,df4 
Each of them have two columns PROPERTIES , AVAILABLE 
PROPERTIES contains name of various properties and AVAILABLE has values 0 or 1 representing if the property is present .
All dataframes have same same set of property names that is assured . I want a venn diagram having 4 circles with respective intersections signifying common properties . How to get this done .

Comment: [google R Venn Diagram](https://www.google.com/#q=R+venn+diagram&*&spf=1)

Comment: I did see a few examples but they are doing it by manually mentioning the intersection part , I have a huge dataset difficult to mention all intersecting areas manually

Comment: Provide sample data using dput(head(data, 20))

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your data looks something like this:

```
ll <- lapply(1:4, function(x) {
    data.frame(PROPERTIES = letters[1:8],
               AVAILABLE = as.logical(rbinom(8, 1, 0.5)),
               ind = x)
  })
```

Notice that I'm using logicals instead of binaries.

First, let's reshape the data to something more useful.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd <- bind_rows(ll) %>%
  spread(ind, AVAILABLE)
```

Which gives us

```
> head(dd)
  PROPERTIES     1     2     3     4
1          a  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
2          b  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
3          c FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4          d  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
5          e  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
6          f  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

We can use the package `eulerr` (that I have developed) to produce a euler diagram from this.

```
library(eulerr)

fit <- euler(dd[, -1])

plot(fit)
```

The result may look something like this:

[image]